# Mypy linting in VSCode Errors out with "Error constructing plugin instance of NewSemanalDRFPlugin"

Tags: python-3.x, django, visual-studio-code, mypy, django-stubs

Trying to run Mypy linter in VSCode, always getting the same error in the output...

The root of the Django project and the workspace directory are different.

```
##########Linting Output - mypy##########
Error constructing plugin instance of NewSemanalDRFPlugin
```

- mypy==0.770
- mypy-extensions==0.4.3
- django-stubs==1.5.0
- djangorestframework-stubs==1.2.0

python3.8.5

Django with DRF

Answer (score 0):

`PYTHONPATH` has to contain the root of your django project, or Mypy has to be called from the root of the django project.

Answer (score 0):

I have got this error when using `django-stubs` and `djangorestframework-stubs` together.
It is probably bug in one of these libraries: https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/issues/672

There is workaround to this (careful, because it can hide other errors). Run mypy with (the `-O` parameter disables assert checks):

```
python -O -m mypy application/
```